# uglifyjs: how to specify max line length when running from shell?

Tags: javascript, shell, uglifyjs

I'm using UglifyJS 3.1.3 (freshly built) and I want to restrict the maximum line length. There is supposed to be a parameter for that, but for the life of me I can't get that to work.

Some documentation mentions `--max-line-length`, others mention `--max_line_length` (note the underscores). I tried this:

```
uglifyjs --mangle --max-line-len 200 -- original.js > ugly.js
uglifyjs --mangle --max_line_len 200 -- original.js > ugly.js
uglifyjs --mangle --max-line-len=200 -- original.js > ugly.js
uglifyjs --mangle --max_line_len=200 -- original.js > ugly.js
```

And they all uglify the .js file but ignore the max line length parameter.

How do I get that working?

Answer (score 0):

According to github [README](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) the correct option is `--max-line-len 32768` where 32768 is default max length of line in characters

Comment: I tried that, see the 1st of my 4 attempts above. Did not work (also not with low numbers or even 1 KB). I'm still getting an output with one long line of almost 30 KB. By the way I very much doubt if this parameter is supposed to work with line length in **KB** rather than characters. But even if it does, it still didn't work for me.

Comment: You are right rtegarding the line length units. It is in characters not KBs! I have edited my answer